# Why do the arrows or the axes labels in a 3D graphic disappear?

Tags: graphics3d

In this 3D graphic, how do I cause both the axes labels *and* the arrows along the axes (with their arrowheads) to appear?

Create the arrows after the `SphericalPlot3D`. The axes labels show, but the arrows do not appear!

```
labelStyle[txt_] := Style[txt, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSlant -> "Italic", Bold, 20]

With[{origin = {0, 0, 0}, radius = 1, mult = 1.5},
  Show[
     SphericalPlot3D[radius, {\[Theta], \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 75], Opacity[0.57, GrayLevel[0.65]]],
       Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 80, 
       MaxRecursion -> 8, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
       AxesLabel -> labelStyle /@ {"y", "x", "z"}, Ticks -> None, 
       PlotRange -> 1.25*radius, AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.0025], 
       ImageSize -> Full
     ],
     Graphics3D[
        {Arrowheads[0.015], Arrow[{origin, {mult*radius, 0, 0}}],
         Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow[{origin, {0, -mult*radius, 0}}],
         Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow[{origin, {0, 0, mult*radius}}]
         }, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Full]
     ]
]
```

[image: Arrows created last but disappear]

Instead, create the arrows before the `SphericalPlot3D`: the arrows show, but the axes labels disappear!

```
With[{origin = {0, 0, 0}, radius = 1, mult = 1.5},
   Show[
      Graphics3D[
        {Arrowheads[0.015], Arrow[{origin, {mult*radius, 0, 0}}],
         Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow[{origin, {0, -mult*radius, 0}}],
         Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow[{origin, {0, 0, mult*radius}}]
        }, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Full],
     SphericalPlot3D[radius, {\[Theta], \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
        PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 75], Opacity[0.57, GrayLevel[0.65]]],
        Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 80, 
        MaxRecursion -> 8, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, 
        AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> labelStyle /@ {"y", "x", "z"}, Ticks -> None, 
       PlotRange -> 1.25*radius, AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.0025], 
       ImageSize -> Full
      ]
   ]
]
```

[image: Arrows created first but axes labels disappear]

Comment: Use `PlotRange -> All` instead of `PlotRange -> 1.25*radius`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: that did it, thanks! (Too obvious?)

Comment: Na, I also had to take a close look. First I tried to enlarged the `Arrowheads` and then I realized that only the tips of the arrow heads were cut of. I was quite puzzled first, in particular because I already added `PlotRange -> All` to the `Show` command. As a hint for the future: Try to put as many plot options in the most outer `Show` command. Within the `Show` command, the inheritence of plot options from the subordinate graphics opjects, while being logically correct and consistent, leads often to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PlotRange -> All` instead of `PlotRange -> 1.25*radius`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be better to drop the axes and the axes labels and label the arrowheads instead. Also, I suggest it is better to give all the options that apply to both the plot and the graphics as options to `Show`.

```
labelStyle[txt_] := 
  Style[txt, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSlant -> "Italic", Bold, 20]

With[{radius = 1, mult = 1.5},
  With[{arrowR = mult*radius, dtext = mult*radius + .1}, 
   Show[
     Graphics3D[
       {Thickness[0.0044], Arrowheads[0.02],
        Arrow[{{-arrowR, 0, 0}, {arrowR, 0, 0}}], 
        Text[labelStyle["y"], {dtext, 0, 0}],
        Arrow[{{0, arrowR, 0}, {0, -arrowR, 0}}], 
        Text[labelStyle["x"], {0, -dtext, 0}],
        Arrow[{{0, 0, -arrowR}, {0, 0, arrowR}}], 
        Text[labelStyle["z"], {0, 0, dtext}]}],
     SphericalPlot3D[radius, {θ, π/2, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 75], Opacity[0.57, GrayLevel[0.65]]],
       Lighting -> "Neutral",
       Mesh -> None, 
       PlotPoints -> 80,
       MaxRecursion -> 8,
       Axes -> False],
     Boxed -> False,
     PlotRange -> All,
     ImageSize -> Full]]]
```

[image: plot]